# K.int_shape of K.zeros_like(x)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Here is my custom padding layer:

```
   class CustomZeroPadding2D(Layer):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(CustomZeroPadding2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        def build(self, input_shape):
            super(CustomZeroPadding2D, self).build(input_shape)

        def call(self, x):
            print('K.int_shape(x)', K.int_shape(x))
            print('K.int_shape(K.zeros_like(x))', K.int_shape(K.zeros_like(x)))
            res = concatenate([x, K.zeros_like(x)], axis=-1)
            return res

        def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
            output_shape = (input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2]*2)
            return output_shape
```

For some reason:

`K.int_shape(x) (None, 128, 128, 7)`

but

`K.int_shape(K.zeros_like(x)) (None, None, None, 7)`

In [doc](https://keras.io/backend/#zeros_like) `instantiates an all-zeros variable of the same shape as another tensor`, so what is wrong?

**Update:**

The problem that concatenations doesn't work:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 128, 128, 7), (None, None, None, 7)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong.

If you were able to concatenate with `axis=-1`, you can be certain that all the three first dimensions were equal.

Now, there might be internal quirks in tensorflow and/or keras, maybe to make things faster, maybe to make them flexible to variable sizes. It's not a big deal.

If you want the true shape of the current values, you need to evaluate (`K.eval()`) the `K.shape(x)` tensor. But evaluating cannot be done inside the layer. It must be done as if it were a prediction.

### The error message

You're using a concatenate **layer**. You should be using `keras.backend.concatenate([...], axis=-1)`

Comment: See update, the problem that concatenations doesn't work because tensors have different shape `(None, 128, 128, 7) vs (None, None, None, 7)`.

Comment: Interesting... but it's talking about a `Concatenate` **layer**, is that really the code you're using?

Comment: I'm using  `concatenate`. Looking at keras source `concatenate` using `Concatenate` inside.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`keras.backend.concatenate` should be used instead of `keras.layers.concatenate`:

```
class CustomZeroPadding2D(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomZeroPadding2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(CustomZeroPadding2D, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x):
        res = K.concatenate([x, K.zeros_like(x)], axis=-1)
        return res

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        output_shape = list(input_shape)
        output_shape[-1] = output_shape[-1] * 2
        output_shape = tuple(output_shape)
        return output_shape
```